# i created a modified pacman, how to make him breath fire?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a modified Pacman, but I want to add a firebolt shooting out from the mouth of the Pacman. My code is:

```
namespace TestingPacman
{
    class Firebolt
    {
        Bitmap firebolt0 = null;
        Bitmap firebolt1 = null;    

        public Point fireboltposition;
        int fireboltwidth = 0;
        int fireboltheight = 0;
        public Firebolt(int x, int y)
        {
            fireboltposition.X = x;
            fireboltposition.Y = y;    
            if (firebolt0 == null)
                firebolt0 = new Bitmap("firebolt0.gif");    
            if (firebolt1 == null)
                firebolt1 = new Bitmap("firebolt1.gif");    
            int fireboltwidth = firebolt0.Width;
            int fireboltheight = firebolt0.Height;
        }

        public Rectangle GetFrame()
        {
            Rectangle Labelrec = new Rectangle(fireboltposition.X, fireboltposition.Y, fireboltwidth, fireboltheight);
            return Labelrec;
        }

        public void Draw(Graphics g)
        {    
            Rectangle fireboltdecR = new Rectangle(fireboltposition.X, fireboltposition.Y, fireboltwidth, fireboltheight);
            Rectangle fireboltsecR = new Rectangle(0, 0, fireboltwidth, fireboltheight);

            g.DrawImage(firebolt0, fireboltdecR, fireboltsecR, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }
```

How can I make a firebolt move in the direction the pacman is facing?
I have a form1 that when I press "F" it will fire a firebolt
but it cant seem to produce the firebolt image. Why is that?

```
namespace TestingPacman
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // int inc = 0;
        Eater TheEater = new Eater(100,100);
        TimeDisplay time = new TimeDisplay();
        int sec = 0;
        Score score = new Score();
        int countofeaten=0;
        Random r = new Random();
        private List<Label> redlabels = new List<Label>();
        private List<Label> bluelabels = new List<Label>();
        Firebolt firebolt;
        List<Firebolt> listfirebolt = new List<Firebolt>();

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);
            TheEater.Draw(g);

            foreach(Firebolt f in listfirebolt)
            f.Draw(g);
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            string result = e.KeyData.ToString();              
            Invalidate(TheEater.GetFrame());
            switch (result)
            {
                case "D1":
                    if (TheEater.eaterwidth >= 9 && TheEater.eaterheight >= 9)
                    {
                        TheEater.eaterwidth++;
                        TheEater.eaterheight++;
                    }
                    break;    
                case "F":
                    listfirebolt.Add(firebolt = new Firebolt(TheEater.Position.X, TheEater.Position.Y));
                    Invalidate(firebolt.GetFrame());                 
                    break;
                case "D2":
                    if (TheEater.eaterwidth > 10 && TheEater.eaterheight > 10)
                    {
                        TheEater.eaterwidth--;
                        TheEater.eaterheight--;
                    }
                    break;    
                case "D9": TheEater.inc=TheEater.inc+2;
                    break;
                case "D0": TheEater.inc=TheEater.inc-2;
                    break;
                case "Left":
                    TheEater.MoveLeft(ClientRectangle);
                    Invalidate(TheEater.GetFrame());
                    break;
                case "Right":
                    TheEater.MoveRight(ClientRectangle);
                    Invalidate(TheEater.GetFrame());
                    break;
                case "Up":
                    TheEater.MoveUp(ClientRectangle);
                    Invalidate(TheEater.GetFrame());
                    break;
                case "Down":
                    TheEater.MoveDown(ClientRectangle);
                    Invalidate(TheEater.GetFrame());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;    
            } 
            RemoveifIntersected();
            }                
            label2.Text = score.Iskore.ToString();

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            label1.Text = time.FormatTime(sec++);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: another thing, i cant make the codes in the same box for ease in reading. why is that?

Comment: You are doing the gaming world a great injustice.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting to close this rather than asking you questions so they can help...

Comment: @jeo: how do you know which direction pacman is facing first of all?

Comment: pass on the direction your pacman is looking into the fireball object when its created.

Comment: nevertheless this is closed, can anyonw with the knwoledge give jeo a hint where he can get help? is there a more specialized stackexchange site?

Comment: some people are just too smart to answer this :( sad for me, got to find the answer the old fashion way :(

Comment: Reopen, I've never seen a PacMan game where PacMan breathes fire. Also its not like op hasn't written some actual code, I've seen much worse questions kept open on SO.

Comment: thats why its a modified pacman, to practice coding skills ,

Comment: Yup thats why I voted to reopen

Comment: My comment was a joke, but when I voted to close I guess I didn't look through the code since it was in its entirety, and I figured it wasn't quite answerable. I voted to reopen so others can help. Sorry about that.

Comment: Here's a starting point: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/99860-creating-games-in-c%23-part-i/ basically when you fire a fireball, you will need to store the orientation of the fireball somehow, then on every game loop move the fireball in that direction at a set rate with collision detection, etc. a simple method is to store the X and Y velocity of the fireball, so if it's shooting Left it would be Y=0, X=-1 then update your fireball position every so often by setting PositionX += VelocityX and PositionY = VelocityY

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jeo, what you are missing in your code is the concept of "Time" as far as I can tell your game only reacts when you press keys. What you really need is a mechanism to pass time in your game. This is almost always done in games with repetitive calls to something called "A Game Loop". Here's a quick example of a game loop that might work for you

```
class Mob
{
  float XPos;
  float YPos;
  float XVel;
  float YVel;
}
List<Mob> EveryThingMovable = new List<Mob>();

void GameLoop() //This loop is called 30 times every second... use a timer or whatever, there are far more sophisticated models, but for a first attaempt at a game it's easiest. 
{
  MoveEverybody(); //make a function that moves everything that can move
  //Later you will have to add collision detection to stop pacman from moving through walls
  CollideFireballs(); //Check if a fireball hits the bad guys
  //More game stuff...



}

void MoveEverybody()
{
  foreach(Mob dude in EverythingMovable)
  { 
     ifDoesntHitWall(dude)
     {
       dude.XPos += dude.XVel;
       dude.YPos += dude.YVel;
     }
  }
}
```

anyways, read up on the idea of a Game Loop, I think it's the biggest hurtle you haven't passed in order to move ahead.

Comment: Exactly right...I was in the process of typing a similar answer. I would only add that you might create a Speed and Direction property on your Firebolt class, and then use those to determine the sprite position for your Draw method. Once you get this hammered out, you might consider looking into XNA, which is custom built for this kind of work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791. I personally feel that this kind of question is absolutely fine for SO, but you might also check out this new stack exchange: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: the problem is i cant even produce the firebolt when i press the F key. if i can produce the firebolt , then i will use time for the movement of the firebolt.

Comment: I suspect that your code is dropping straight through Form1_KeyDown. That would be the simplest way this wouldn't work...alternately fireBolt0.width and/or height is 0. Stick a debugger on it and that should tell you pretty quickly what the problem is.